Why does my dropdown menu expand upwards instead of downwards in my component?
Description:
I'm working on a dropdown menu in my React component. When I click a list item to expand a dropdown menu, it expands upwards instead of expanding downwards as expected. I want the dropdown to smoothly expand downward without any unexpected upward movement.
Problem:
When clicking on a dropdown item, the submenu unexpectedly expands upward instead of expanding downward. This is not the desired behavior, and I'd like to fix it so the dropdown opens smoothly downwards.
What I've Tried:
I've tried adjusting CSS properties like overflow, max-height, and position but haven't found a solution that prevents the upward expansion.
Could someone help me figure out how to make the dropdown expand downward correctly?
{open && (
                <>
                <div className={`w-full bg-customYellow relative h-[50vh] transition-transform duration-800 ease-in-out flex justify-center flex-col items-center`}>
                 <ul className={`w-full flex items-center flex-col gap-0 ${journal ? 'gap-0 absolute overflow-hidden' : 'gap-0 ' }`}>
                    
                        <li className={`w-[80%] flex justify-center gap-3 items-center font-annie text-[1.5rem] border-b-[1px]  text-customBrown  ${journal ? 'pb-0  overflow-hidden' : 'pb-0' }`} onClick={JournalOpen}>{Journal} <li><ChevronDownIcon className="w-6 h-6"/></li></li>
                        {journal && (
                            <ul className={`w-full flex flex-col items-center overflow-hidden relative `}>
                                <li>Lorem</li>
                                <li>Ipsum</li>
                                <li>Dolor</li>
                            </ul>
                    )}
                  
                   

                    
                        <li className="w-[80%] flex justify-center gap-3 items-center font-annie text-[1.5rem] border-b-[1px]  text-customBrown pb-3" onClick={CommunityOpen}>{Community} <li><ChevronDownIcon className="w-6 h-6"/></li></li>
                        {community && (
                             <ul>
                             <li>Lorem</li>
                             <li>Ipsum</li>
                             <li>Dolor</li>
                         </ul>
                    )}
                    
                    
                   
                 </ul>


Hard to ascertain without a codesandbox reproduction, but more than likely its because the contents of the dropdown, once rendered, are centered vertically in the containing ul. Since the whole thing, including the list, is now "taller" once said list is opened, everything within that ul will shift upwards in order to achieve that vertical center. Typically you'd use something like https://floating-ui.com/  (has react bindings) to do this, as there's more to it in many use cases than just CSS. That will render the list in a fixed position, over the top, which gives true overlay behavior.
